# What's the simplest way to store data from a java program to MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to store data in string form to MySQL. I have created the tables in the MySQL.
I haven't worked with DATABASE ever. Can you please provide me code to store that data in the MySQL DB.
e.g. Let's say I have a string "stack_overflow" and there is a column "SiteName" in a table "SiteDetails" in the DataBase.
So how to store the string "stack_overflow" in the column "SiteName".

Comment: Do you have a JDBC connection setup?  You can't do anything with the database until you have a connection to it: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/ConnectMySql.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should start from the Java [JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html). After you understand what is happening there you will need a JDBC driver for MySQL.

Comment: I see the other answers mention Hibernate and iBatis. In real-life large-scale project you will need a framework like those. However it is important, in my opinion, to first understand the basics of JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading about a few technologies so you can learn the framework ways of doing this stuff.  Such as [JPA](http://java.sun.com/javaee/overview/faq/persistence.jsp) or [OJB](http://db.apache.org/ojb/).  However, to directly answer your question, the easiest way would be with straight SQL over a JDBC connection.

```
 insert into SiteDetails (ID, SiteName)
 values(1, 'stackoverflow')
```

or

```
update SiteDetails 
set SiteName = 'stackoverflow'
where ID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [PreparedStatement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the Hibernate project. While it may not be simpler right now, as your application grows it will prove to be a life saver. [Hibernate.org](https://www.hibernate.org/152.html)

Comment: Hibernate is not the right solution for the questioner as he mentioned that he never worked with databases.

Comment: I know Hibernate is the best option for that but as I have an urgent requirement to store the data, I need the simplest solution and I can't spend time on learning the Hibernate.

Comment: Therefore I assume they don't know SQL either. So an ORM in this case makes more sense if not for that very reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is iBatis which works great and gives you control of your query